# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found. JavaFX image

Tags: java, image, file, resources, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox API V2 to download images from my Dropbox to my Java Program. I save them in `"/src/main/Resources/Downloads/"` and then want to get the `image.jpg` at the same time the program is running after downloaded.

1) The first time the program downloads the image and run this I get "Invalid URL or resource not found" error:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
Image thumbnail = new Image("/Downloads/image.jpg");
button1.setGraphic(new ImageView(thumbnail));
```

2) Second time when I have closed the program and the file is already saved in Resources it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: The image probably wasn't saved at the time of / before the call in #1.

Comment: are you sure the download function returns AFTER the image has downloaded successfully? Put in a sleep of sufficient time to test this

Comment: I just made a Thread.sleep(70000) just to be super sure. But still didn't do the trick. It seems like the images downloaded isn't saved in resource folder until I close the program.

Comment: Please use a code block {} instead of quotes to highlight your code - it will look better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
String path = "/src/main/Resources/";

File file = new File(path + i.getLocalPathThumbnail());
String localUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
Image thumbnail = new Image(localUrl, false);
```

Comment: A better method is to use `file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()`